# NSDate stringFromDate returning null error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm setting a date from a subtitle text in a UITableViewCell. The subtitle text is dynamically generated and will be in the format "August 21, 2013". I'm trying to check if the date in the subtitle text is greater than 90 days from the current date [nsdate date], but I get the following error.

```
Before anything: (null)
2013-08-21 23:01:00.656 athletes[806:60b] After NSDate Conversion: (null)
2013-08-21 23:01:00.660 athletes[806:60b] *** -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: fromDate cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil fromDate?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
NSString *detailTextDate = lastEval.date_recorded;
NSLog(@"Before anything: %@",detailTextDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];
NSLog(@"After NSDate Conversion: %@",startDate);
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate:startDate
                                                      toDate:todaysDate
                                                     options:0];
if(components.day >= 90 && lastEval.date_recorded != nil){
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ was last evaluated on :%@. It has been over 3 months since their last evaluation.",athlete.first, lastEval.date_recorded];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Comment: As your logs saying, your `detailTextDate` is `NULL` that's why you code is crashing. Double check how you are getting `detailTextDate` `lastEval.date_recorded`.

Comment: And you have really nice and funny exception handler in there :)

Comment: first check it about "lastEval.date_recorded"? value

Comment: Also check if "lastEval" is nil. If it is, then any attempt to access properties on it will also return nil.

Comment: @FahriAzimov: Thanks. Figured it out. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your TableViewCell. The `NSLog(@"Before anything...)`already prints out `(null)`. So `detailTextDate`does not have any value.

Comment: This was it. I added an if statement as follows: if(lastEval.date_recorded != nil){} and that took care of it. Thanks.